# How can std::function be copied if it captures a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

struct PacketFrom
{
    typedef std::unique_ptr<PacketFrom> SPtr;
};

template<class P> 
class R{
    public:
    void queue_read(P *t)
    {
        doSomething([t = typename PacketFrom::SPtr(t)](){test(std::move(t));});
    }

    void doSomething(std::function<void()> f) {

    }

    void test(PacketFrom::SPtr p) {

    }
};

int main()
{
    R<PacketFrom> r;

    return 0;
}
```

How can this code work if the lambda function is being passed by copy? The lambda owns a `unique_ptr` which cannot be copied. I thought it was simply not capturing the unique_ptr so I added `test()` just to be sure it was capturing. However the code compiles fine.

Comment: Nothing is copied here. `f` is move-constructed from the lambda expression in `queue_read`. But it still shouldn't work because in `doSomething` you no longer know that `f` can't be copied.

Comment: clang errors; g++ and MSVC compile: https://godbolt.org/z/Nuv-hn suggest [language-lawyer] tag

Comment: Always keep in mind that C++ has this unique failure mode where asking the compiler "is this a valid program" has false positives..

Comment: `(t)](){test(std::move(t));});` Is it normal to have so many ()()({][][}}[[]]{]]())(( without spaces in C++?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This code doesn't actually "work" in that sense. It compiles, but only because you don't ever call `queue_read`.

If you try to use it (which forces the compiler to actually instantiate the `R<P>::queue_read`, which it doesn't have to do until that point) then you get an error from every compiler:

```
template<class P> 
class R{
    public:
    void queue_read(P *t)
    {
        doSomething([this, t = std::unique_ptr<P>(t)]() { test(std::move(t)); });
    }

    void doSomething(std::function<void()> f) {
        (void)f;
    }

    void test(std::unique_ptr<P> p) {
        (void)p;
    }
};

int main()
{
    R<int> r;
    r.queue_read(new int(1));

    return 0;
}
```

clang 9.0:

> ```
> error: call to deleted constructor of 'std::unique_ptr<int>'
>     doSomething([this, t = std::unique_ptr<P>(t)]() { test(std::move(t)); });
> ```

gcc 9.2:

> ```
> error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]'
> 11 |         doSomething([this, t = std::unique_ptr<P>(t)]() { test(std::move(t)); });
> ```

MSVC 19.22:

> ```
> error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<P,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
> ```

https://godbolt.org/z/KmjVJB (thanks Richard!)

Again, the key here is that the compiler didn't actually compile the code of `queue_read` because there was no need. The function is implicitly `inline` by virtue of being defined within the class body. Instantiating `R<P>` for some `P` causes only the *declarations*, but not the *definitions* of its member functions to be instantiated. Only once you actually call `queue_read` does the compiler have to complain.

This is a good thing by the way. You can use `std::vector<MoveOnlyType>` and do everything that doesn't require copying, even though some of the `std::vector` member functions require a copyable type. But as long as you never use the latter functions, everything is fine. If the compiler always instantiated all the member function definitions and reported errors in those (even if never used) it would be way more cumbersome.

Comment: https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3/blob/275cf80efb7a08adc920f7ca49075c776e596b08/openvpn/tun/tunio.hpp#L212 do you have any idea of why the same code works here? I've written my question from here, but it shouldn't work. However it works

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs If you give me links to the classes `TunIO` is instantiated with I can take a look, but I don't have the time to dig for some instantiation and the definitions of the classes used as template parameters of `TunIO` in there myself.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs `async_read_some` doesn’t accept a `std::function` but a `HANDLER&&`, where `HANDLER` is a template type. In other words, nothing to see here: the lambda is moved into the function.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs There is no same code there. I see neither `std::unique_ptr` nor `std::function`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph but when I call async_read_some with a lambda as a parameter, what is the template that it uses? I thougth it was an std::function

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs No. Each lambda has a unique, un-nameable type. That's the type that the template parameter will have. Think of it as `struct __SOME_HASH__ { auto operator()(/* your arguments */) { /* your code */ }; /* your captures */ };` - on a high level. If `std::function` didn't exist, lambdas would work exactly like they do right now (but accepting a capturing lambda into a non-templated method would require essentially a `std::function` reimplementation). Lambdas are not a `std::function` and do not "decay" to them automatically (but can be converted to them seamlessly).

Answer (score 11):

> How can std::function be copied if it captures an unique_ptr?

A `std::function` doesn't capture anything.

A lambda that captures a non-copyable object such as `std::unique_ptr` is itself non-copyable. Such lambda doesn't satisfy, nor does any other non-copyable function object type satisfy the requirements of `std::function` which requires the functor to be copyable. Standard rule (from latest draft):

> [func.wrap.func.con]
>
> ```
> template<class F> function(F f);
> ```
>
> Requires: F shall be Cpp17CopyConstructible.

---

> However the code compiles fine.

This is typical when the ill-formed function is an unused function of a template. It should fail to compile if you attempt to call the function.